# Render Google Fusion Tables Layer Tiles in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

I would like to know if there is a way now to include Google Fusion Table Layers Tiles in OpenLayers, and **if yes, is it possible to use the dynamic styling just like in Google Maps?**

I know you can use Vizualisation or FusionTableAPI to render Fusion Table Layers in geoJSON, but tiling is much more performant.

This [example](http://projects.bryanmcbride.com/sandbox/OL_google_tests.html) is it valid? I dont understand how it mixes Fusion Table Layers Tiles and OpenLayers.

Comment: If you view the source of the example link you provided you'll notice a piece of code like this "var fusionlayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(139529);
".  The 139529 parameter refers to the numeric id of the FusionTable. You can find the ID of your FT by clicking the "File" menu, then "About this table".

Comment: exact, but I dont understand why its not working with the usual new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: 'id',
        where: "condition"})

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question to include the info from your last comment.  I'm not well versed enough in javascript to help much further.  One possible workaround is to perform the sql statement on your FusionTable ahead of time...get the results how you'd like them...then save this as a copy of the original FT.  Then use the template you pointed to, replacing the parameters with that of your new copy.